# Nestjs/TypeORM - How to implement custom search by column

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am playing around with NestJs using TypeORM along with MySQL.

I have went via [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing), and I have made basic CRUD app running locally.
I have built in searches (via Repository) by id, but I would need to implement search by custom column as well.

For example I have this entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  first_name: string;

  @Column()
  last_Name: string;

  @Column()
  gender: string;
```

And in my repository, I have these built in methods:

```
async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(id: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
  }
```

And it works just fine, as expected. I would need another custom search, so I can search also by username, how can I achieve that?
I would need something like this:

```
findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.findByUsername(username);
  }
```

I assume I have to implement custom query, but I have no clue where to do it :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the simpler solution:

```js
findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne({ username }); 
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know where is this documented? I would like to read about it a bit.

Comment: not sure where i read it before :) but you can check the typescript definition files of the TypeOrm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
findByName(user_name: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne({ user_name }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve it, by using [queryBuilder](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/what-is-querybuilder)

So this is how my function looks now:

```
findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    const user = getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder("user")
      .where("user.username = :username", { username: username })
      .getOne();

    return user;
  }
```

Comment: How can we compare if string is non case sensitive?

Answer (score -2):

```
const firstUser = await connection
    .getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .getOne();
```

Comment: Can you please provide at least some explanation